# Проблема с нахождением минимального значения

Tags: c++, массивы

*Необходимо найти минимальное значение массива С[i]

Проблема в том, что по какой-то причине, вместо минимального значения массива выдает число : *-858993460*

```
#include <iostream>
 #include <conio.h>
 #include <string>
 #include <algorithm>
 using namespace std;
 int main() {
 int a, b, c;
 cin >> a; 
 cin >> b;
 cin >> c;
 int A[1000];
 int B[1000];
 int f, v;
 for (int i =0; i <a; i++){
    cin >> A[i];

 }for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    cin >> B[i];
 }
 int C[1000];
 int min = C[0];

 for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {

    C[i] = c + B[i] * b - A[i];


 }
 for (int i= 0; i<a; i++){

 if (C[i] < min) {
        min = C[i];
    }

 }
 cout << min;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Продолжая ответ Ant'а

Поместите инициализацию переменной после цикла for:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
  C[i] = c + B[i] * b - A[i];
}
int min = C[0];
```

Comment: Все работает! Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

У вас `min` изначально инициализируется бессмысленным значением, "мусором"

```
int C[1000];
int min = C[0];
```

Поведение не определено. Из этого все и вытекает. Собственно ваше `-858993460` - это и есть этот "мусор".